# Do humans have skin cells that trigger oxytocin release in the brain?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, endocrinology, neurophysiology, touch

I was reading an article by Montgomery on the therapeutic effect of pets ([Boston Globe, January 12, 2015](https://www.bostonglobe.com/lifestyle/2015/01/12/your-brain-pets/geoJHAfFHxrwNS4OgWb7sO/story.html)), and I found this quote:

> **All animals appear to have cells directly under the skin that activate oxytocin in the brain. So gentle touch** — from grooming your
>   horse’s coat to making love with your spouse — is a powerful trigger.
>   But so is simply thinking about someone you love, whether it’s a
>   person or a pet. And in fact, a small study published this fall at
>   Massachusetts General Hospital found that MRI scans of women’s brains
>   lit up in the same areas when shown pictures of their pets as when
>   shown pictures of their children.

**Do humans have oxytocin triggering skin cells or formations under the skin?** If so, are there higher concentrations of these cells in certain areas of the body? In the human erogenous zones, like neck, lips, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**
Oxytocin release has been associated with the cutaneous low-threshold (CT) afferent fibers in hairy skin.

**Background**
Oxytocin is released from the paraventricular nucleus in the brain in response to low intensity stimulation of the skin, such as touch, stroking and warm temperatures.

In a recent review [Uvnäs-Moberg et al. (2015)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4290532/) report that the specific sensory nerve type mediating oxytocin release in the brain is unknown. Although myelinated somatosensory fibers mediating the **discriminative sense of touch** may be involved, a more likely candidate mediating **affective touch** are the unmyelinated low-threshold mechanosensory nerves, called **C low-threshold mechanoreceptors** (CLTMs) in animals or **C-tactile afferents** (CTs) in humans. Their terminal morphology (i.e., the skin receptor they connect to) is currently unknown. The fibers have been characterized mainly through  electrophysiological and electron microscopy research [(McGlone at al., 2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627314003870).

The association of CT fibers with **affective** touch stems mainly from the finding that their activation patterns with various stroking velocities correlates with subjective pleasantness ratings. Specifically, the relationship between brush-stroking velocity and firing rate was distinctly different between CT and myelinated afferents. CTs showed an inverted U-shaped relationship,
whereas mean firing rates increased monotonically with brushing velocity in all myelinated afferents [(McGlone at al., 2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627314003870).

However, CT fibers have only been identified in hairy skin in mammals, and the fibers mediating affective touch through glabrous skin (including the fingertips, palms and lips) are unknown [(McGlone at al., 2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627314003870).

<sub>**References**

**-** [McGlone *et al.*, *Neuron* (2014); **82**: 737-55](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627314003870)

**-** [Uvnäs-Moberg *et al*., *Front Neurosci* (2015); **5**(1529): 1-16](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4290532/)</sub>

Comment: to clarify - are hairs involved in triggering those fibers? For example, would a person who undergone laser hair removal feel the same as a hairy person?

Comment: @AlexStone:  *Their terminal morphology (i.e., the skin receptor they connect to) is currently unknown* This includes the hair follicle receptors.